# General method for extracting graphics primitives from a plot

Tags: graphics

I often have to plot experimental data that is very noisy, and sometimes I try a bit of image processing on it.
For example (using a test function) I can gaussian filter it:

```
fdp = DensityPlot[x + y Sin[x y], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, Frame -> False];
GaussianFilter[fdp, 6]
```

But this way what I'm doing is image-processing the plot itself - using the trick that there are no axes, labels...

There is a general way to extract the data from a plot, filter it , and put it back (with its axes and so on...)?

Comment: Look up `Cases[]`, `GraphicsComplex[]`, and maybe `Normal[]`.

Comment: It seems to me that you are going about this backwards. You are generating the plot, so you already have the data in some form. I would think that you should then process the data *first* with whatever smoothing method you like, and then plot the smoothed version.

Comment: If you have your data in `data`, how do you generate the plot?  Aren't you concerned that the plotted image may only be a rough approximation of your data, and maybe a very bad approximation if scalars were replaced by colors?  Why not `GaussianFilter[data, 6]`?

Comment: I joined others in voting to close this.  It appears to be an atypical operation; if there is *really* need to post-process the output of `DensityPlot` you should explain the motivation behind it and elaborate on the class of operations you wish to attempt.  Perhaps you are merely looking for a way to reduce the artifacts produced in `fdp`?  Try `DensityPlot[x + y Sin[x y], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure if I understand your question, but I'll try an answer. You can extract data like so an store them in a variable;

```
data = Table[
  x + y Sin[x y], {x, Range[0, 12, 0.1]}, {y, Range[0, 12, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

A plot of the data shows us that we are not deviated, please note that I have, for obvious reasons a small increment of 0.1 selected;

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image]

Since you can do pretty much anything with a list in MMA;

```
myGauss = GaussianFilter[data, 6]
```

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[myGauss]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that was what I needed!